# Why does wc get wrong result with output from ps

Tags: ps, wc

To output all lines into a file `/tmp/ps.txt`

```
$ ps -e >/tmp/ps.txt
```

To count it with wc -l

```
$ wc -l /tmp/ps.txt
172
```

To count it without exporting a file.

```
$ ps -e | wc -l
173
```

Why `ps -e | wc -l`  get one more line?

I don't think [ctrl-d has the right explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336145/100397) for my question.

```
$ echo "test" | wc -l
1
```

Please try it in your terminal, it would yield 2 as [ctrl-d would say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336145/100397).

Comment: You are counting 1 for the one line that you are echoing to wc. That's a different situation than with ps.

Comment: Your commands are counting the number of processes running on the machine **at the time the ps was run**.  Since in the first case, where you use a file, the wc is run separately, so not in the ps.  When you run it as a pipe the wc is running at the same time and so it is another process in the ps output, thus the count.  You could see the difference by adding a `tee` to the pipeline (which will increase the number by one more, of course) whichn will produce a file you can look at and see the `ps`, `wc` and `tee` processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ctrl-d's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336145/135943) is correct.

You appear not to have understood what the `ps` command is *for*.  It lists processes on your system.

When you run the `ps` command, that running instance *itself* is a process.

When you run the `wc` command, that is also a process.

If you stick some `cat` commands in the pipeline, each of those is also a process and each will cause `ps` to output one more line of information:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps | wc -l
4
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps | cat | wc -l
5
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps | cat | cat | wc -l
6
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps | wc -l
4
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
22912 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
29651 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

---

The fact that `echo "test" | wc -l` displays "1" is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 11):

The extra line is the wc program that is running. It is executed at the same time as ps, not after that.